# nativescript IQKeyboardManager plugin is throwing Unable to find a specification error

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am currently using nativescript to create mobile app, I found one annoying issue, the soft input key is coverting the TextView component.
After checking website, I found this plugin - nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager, but after I run tns plugin add, and then run tns run ios, I found this error:

```
Analyzing dependencies

[!] Unable to find a specification for `IQKeyboardManager (~> 4.0.0)` Unable to apply changes on device: 7F714272-BD81-4B77-8D6C-1CD96CEC7BF7. Error is: Command pod failed with exit code 1 Error output:   

[!] Automatically assigning platform ios with version 8.0 on target rsshoc5new because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`. .
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have cocoapods installed? Try 'pod repo update' in a Terminal window (folder doesn't matter).

Comment: excellent! It worked

Comment: Awesome - I've posted the same as a 'real' answer so it's more obvious to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have cocoapods installed? Try 'pod repo update' in a Terminal window (folder doesn't matter).